# transform pandas dataframe and combine rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like that:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      student-id     |     subject-id   |       grade      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        1234      |        4         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        2234      |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        3234      |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        1234      |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        2234      |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        3234      |        4         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

now I want to transform it, that I get only one row for every student-id with every grade from this student in this row like that:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      student-id     |      grade 1     |       grade 2    |      grade 3     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        4         |        3         |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        2         |        1         |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

thx for help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

you may drop `subject-id` by `del df['column_name']` and then `df.groupBy['student-id']` will give grades with respect to student-id.